# Connecting to java RMI server

Tags: java, netbeans, rmi

I am new to java RMI, i was following a tutorial to learn about it. It uses a server, the code listing is as below for getting to the server

1. CalculatorServer.java

   ```
    public class CalculatorServer {
           public CalculatorServer(){
               try {
                   Calculator c = new CalculatorImpl();
                   Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/CalculatorService", c);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   System.out.println("Trouble"+e);
               }
           }
           public static void main(String args[]){
               new CalculatorServer();
           }
       }
   ```
2. CalculatorImpl.java

   ```
    public class CalculatorImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Calculator {

       //constructor
       public CalculatorImpl() throws RemoteException {
           super();
       }

       //@Override
       public long add(long a, long b) throws RemoteException {
           return a + b;
       }

       //@Override
       public long sub(long a, long b) throws RemoteException {
           return a - b;
       }

       //@Override
       public long mul(long a, long b) throws RemoteException {
           return a * b;
       }

      // @Override
       public long div(long a, long b) throws RemoteException {
           return a / b;
       }
   }
   ```

3.Calculator.java

```
  public interface Calculator extends Remote{
    public long add(long a, long b) throws RemoteException;
    public long sub(long a, long b) throws RemoteException;
    public long mul(long a, long b) throws RemoteException;
    public long div(long a, long b) throws RemoteException;
  }
```

When i debug the program, here is the error by netbeans ide console;
it says this error : Troublejava.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmi.Calculator

Comment: the rmiregistry must have the interface classes on it's classpath.

Comment: can you post the client code please ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not running the RMI registry, which is a separate process from your CalculatorServer program. It is be located in your java bin directory. Give it a moment to start up, then try your code again.

Comment: and how do i start it so that i can try again?

Comment: To start the RMI registry, you must find "rmiregistry.exe", which will be located in your Java directory. If you're having trouble finding it, try searching for it (probably on your C drive).

Comment: Thanks for the path issue, it helped me a lot and now the server is up, I have edited the question and added more modules for error clarity

Comment: Not running the RMI Registry does *not* cause ClassNotFoundExceptions. -1

Comment: This answer was written before Alphy edited to add his problems with exceptions. His first problem was, in fact, that he was not running the RMI registry.
As for Alphy's new issues, I would point you to a decent guide at http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~cs379/DistributedSystems/rmi_tut.html. It talks about how to make your classes accessible to the RMI registry.